# Variable interpolation in Alpine.js & Spruce

Tags: pug, alpine.js

I have a scenario where I fetch data from an API and create a unique store object for each entry of the array in the response. Here's an example (using Pug and [Spruce](https://spruce.ryangjchandler.co.uk/))

```
template(x-for='entry in data')
    li.list__entry(x-init='saveToStore("plan", entry.id, data.plan)')
script.
    function saveToStore(sheet, rowID, data) {
        Spruce.store(`${sheet}-${rowID}`, data);
    }
```

Now the problem is, how do I access this dynamically created store key in Alpine.js using the `entry.id` of the `x-for` loop?
I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
template(x-if=`$store.plan-${entry.id}`)
    span(x-text=`$store.plan-${entry.id}.name`)
```

How to solve this? Or any tip for another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work?

```
template(x-if="$store[`plan-${entry.id}`]")
    span(x-text="$store[`plan-${entry.id}`].name")
```

Issue I can see in your code is that you're trying to use `$store.` (dot notation) for a dynamic key, for which you need to use `[]` (square bracket/computed key notation)

Comment: Hey @hugo thanks for answering fast. Unfortunately no, seems like `${entry.id}` is not referring to the entry variable in the `x-for` loop. So I get a Pug error that entry in undefined. Btw. i think the backticks need to be outside instead of inside the bracket notation, otherwise it's just a plain string. Like this: 

`template(x-if=\`$store[plan-${entry.id}]\`)`

Comment: I've also tried to do something like this:
`template(x-if='$store.plan[entry.id]')` - So instead of creating a store like `plan-xy` i nest the `xy` in a store object called `plan`. Anyway, this is not working either. If I call it this way, Alpine tells me that `entry` is not defined. If I call it this way: `template(x-if=\`$store.plan[${entry.id}]\`)` Pug throws an error that entry is not defined.

Comment: So the issue is with the pug templating?

Comment: Not really. My main problem is: How can i do interpolation of an Alpine.js variable within another attribute? Like taking the variable `entry` of an `x-for` loop and then use it in an attribute of a child node like: `<div x-if="`somePrefix-${entry.id}`">` or `<div x-if="somePrefix-"+entry.id>`

Comment: `somePrefix-something` won't be valid JS